# Sequence in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum, window-functions

I need to create SELECT statement with sequence in Oracle. When col_flag is 1 then sequence increase with  mod(col_seq, max_seq) and when col_flag is 0 then sequence don't increment.

Example:

```
col_group col_flag  col_seq 
--------- --------  --------
A         1         1
A         1         2
A         1         3
A         0         3
A         0         3
B         1         4
B         1         1
B         1         2
B         1         3
B         0         3
B         1         4
B         1         1
C         1         2
C         0         2 
...
```

Comment: What is the rule that resets the sequence? And what is `max_seq`?

Comment: max_seq is maximum count of seq. In example is 4

Answer (score 0):

It *guess* that a window sum and arithmetics can do what you want - but you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows, I assumed `id`.

```
select col_flag,
    mod(sum(col_flag) over(order by id), 4) + 1 col_seq
from mybltae
```